# what is the termination condition for this C for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, null-pointer

i found the linked [code](https://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/dfa0.c.txt) and found this for loop which is a bit strange for me. i would appreciate if someone could explain me the syntax of this loop to me.
MFG

```
void patch(Ptrlist *l, State *s)
{
    Ptrlist *next;
    
    for(; l; l=next){
        next = l->next;
        l->s = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined because 'next' is used uninitialized.

Comment: @MartinJames There is neither undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop

```
for(; l; l=next){
```

is equivalent to

```
for(; l != NULL; l=next){
```

or

```
for(; l != 0; l=next){
```

That is the for loop is executed until the controlling expression is equal to 0.